# cookie produced based on select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have this jsFiddle I have worked on to produce a slide down effect on a div based on the select.  I need to produce a cookie when the selection is made so when the page is reloaded, the div remains open.  Not sure how to produce this effect in the code.  Any help is really appreciated!

Heres the link for a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/J9uuL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a plugin such as https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie ?

If so just use its sytax

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

in your change listener. And then attempt to read the cookie value ondomready.

EDIT:

Untested but maybe something like this (if you can use the plugin I mentioned):

```
var c = $.cookie("selectedNum");
if (c) {
    $('#book_list').val(c);
    $('#' + c).slideDown("slow");
}

$('div.book').css("display", "none");
$('#book_list').change(function() {
    $('div.book').slideUp("fast");
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
    $.cookie("selectedNum", $(this).val() === "" ? null : $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the cookie info...how would I incorporate the cookie into the code...what would be the code I would put in to keep the div open?

Comment: ...And I apologize, Im new to all of this, what is the change listener and the ondomready?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#book_list').change(function() {
    $('div.book').slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
    setCookie('divSelected', $(this).val());
});

if(getCookie('divSelected')){
    $("#book_list option[value='" + getCookie('divSelected') + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');   
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
     var exdate=new Date();
     exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
     var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
     document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}


function getCookie(c_name){
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't test it with jsfiddle, since I don't think they handle cookies correctly, I used the cookie code from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.